# How to debug MVC Controller URL mapping in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application runnign Kafka and JPA. I wanted add an admin page & so started off by adding "spring-boot-starter-web" and adding Controller class. However when I start my application, I can see that the Tomcat server has started and dispatcherServlet is initialized.

```
2018-04-13 18:25:29.495  INFO 5512 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f5f4a697] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying) 
2018-04-13 18:25:30.584  INFO 5512 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-04-13 18:25:30.604  INFO 5512 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-04-13 18:25:30.607  INFO 5512 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.27
2018-04-13 18:25:33.052  INFO 5512 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded
JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2018-04-13 18:25:33.384  INFO 5512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-04-13 18:25:33.384 DEBUG 5512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT] 
2018-04-13 18:25:33.385  INFO 5512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization comp
leted in 6776 ms
2018-04-13 18:25:33.761  INFO 5512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-04-13 18:25:33.768  INFO 5512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
```

But I cannot see the Controller class getting mapped with the handlerMapping. Calling http://localhost:8080 only gives me a server unavailable error.

How can I debug this? I already checked the following:

1. Controller class is in a subfolder of the main Application.java
   file.
2. Controller has the @Controller annotation. Other @Components in that package are getting autowired so I am sure that folder is
   scanned.
3. I have extended the SpringBootServletInitializer class in the main class.
4. There are the following annotations in the main class
   -@SpringBootApplication
   @Import(PersistenceConfig.class), @EnableKafka, @EnableCaching, @EnableWebMvc,
   @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { KafkaAutoConfiguration.class })
   Here PersistenceConfig is my own class.

Is there a way to find out why the Controller classes are not being added to URL mapping by the MVC?

I cannot share the code since it is not public. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: You **can** share the code by by creating a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I can get simple Spring Boot app with JSP & tomcat  to work. The issue is with my existing project that has a lot of components - Kafka consumers/producers, JPA, etc. If there is a way to trace the component scan or the MVC init process, I think I will get some idea.

Comment: You can get the applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); and then String[] allBeanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames(); to see if it has been loaded. Or use actuator <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency> The Spring Boot Actuator functionality provides endpoints which are used for monitoring our application’s statistics.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi thanks. Your answer got me closer to the problem. When I tried to print the bean names, I saw that the run() method did not return the bean names, because the context was till loading. The issue was that there was a bean that was loading data on startup and hence the context was not ready to serve requests to mapped URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved. I found that I could not access the Actuator, or any of the mapped URLs. I kept seeing a "page not available" error from the browser (Not a 404).

It was because the ApplicationContext was still loading. The app context was waiting for a bean initialization that took a long time to load a hashmap from the database. So the context was not ready to serve requests to mapped URLs.

I got confused on seeing the Tomcat server startup message in the logs. That was just the server. The web application context was not ready when I accessed the URLs.

After I removed the slow bean, I was able to access the URLs. Thanks for all the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to find out why the Controller classes are not being added to URL mapping by the MVC?

It's always hard to find out why something is *not* happening (unless it prevents startup), but there's one configuration item in Tomcat that might come in handy to debug this issue:

Set [`logEffectiveWebXml="true"` on your context](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html) and see the effective web.xml in your logs - from there you should be able to identify if the URL handling *is* wired, or maybe overloaded or somehow else preempted.

Comment: What is the config property to enable this in embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot?